# Assert key name in the json response using groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I want to assert a key in the json response.

Response

```
{
  "availableRooms": [
    {
      "roomId": 2,
      "exchangeEmailId": null,
      "roomName": "Room 1",
      "floor": 0,
      "groupID": 3,
      "defaultCapacity": 8,
      "maxCapacity": 8,
      "attributes": [
        {
          "attributeID": 170,
          "displayName": "Video Conference Unit",
          "abbreviation": "VCU"
        }
      ],
      "externalRoomEmail": "vinay.jaiswal@condecosoftware.com"
    }
  ],
  "availableRoomsForAllDates": {},
  "callResponse": {
    "message": null,
    "customResponseCode": null
  }
}
```

Groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
if( jsonSlurper.containsKey( 'externalRoomEmail' ) ) 
{
    log.info 'a'
}
else
{
    log.info 'b'
}
```

Output

```
Tue Nov 24 20:24:35 IST 2020:INFO:b
```

Is there any inbuilt method?

If I try jsonSlurper.availableRooms.externalRoomEmail then it gives me null but testcase is passed.

I want that it should break the testcase if key not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<edit - just re-read your question, answer adjusted accordingly>**

First of all I'm going to call your parsed json `json` instead of `jsonSlurper` as the slurper is the groovy class used to parse json and it's conceptually confusing to name the data "slurper".

So your problem is that `json.availableRooms` returns a list. In other words you would have to use something like:

```
if(json.availableRooms.first().externalRoomEmail) { 
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

to check if the first room had an `externalRoomEmail` defined.

From there is depends on what you want to do. Let's say that you wanted to see if *any* of the available rooms had an `externalRoomEmail` defined, you would then do something like:

```
def roomsWithEmails = json.availableRooms.findAll { it.externalRoomEmail }
if (roomsWithEmails) {
  roomsWithEmails.each { room ->
    println "room ${room.roomName} has external email ${room.externalRoomEmail}"
  }
} else { // no rooms with externalRoomEmail
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.